# how can i create a custom list in android fragment with onClick for different items in list?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-listfragment

can i use ListFragment to achieve what I said above or i need a custom recycler view inside a fragment, I tried to put a recycler view inside fragment but i didn't know how to make the onClick for recycler view work with fragment so it passes data to another fragment or another activity in case of multi-pane UI, so can i use list fragment or my only choice is recycler view, if it's then how can I do it in recycler view ?

my MainActivity which has a fragment that contains the recycler view

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment_container);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new FragmentRecyclerList();

        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}
}
```

my fragment which contains the recycler view

```
public class FragmentRecyclerList extends Fragment implements MyDialog.OnInputSelected {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
private List<String> titles;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

public FragmentRecyclerList() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_recycler_list, container, false);
}

void showDialog() {
    MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
    myDialog.setTargetFragment(FragmentRecyclerList.this, 1);
    myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    fab = getView().findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

    titles = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), titles);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog();
        }
    });


}
}
```

my recycler view adapter 
     public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
     RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<String> titles;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> titles) {
    this.context = context;
    this.titles = titles;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_wallpaper
            , parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String title = titles.get(position);
    holder.tvTitle.setText(title);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return titles.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvTitle;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        View v = itemView;
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: i cleared some of the unnecessary code, and like i said i just want to have a custom list in my fragment that by clicking on it to open a new activity or update a fragment data, so i wondered if i can only do that with recycler view or i can do it with ListFragment too and have a different click for different items in the custom list.

Comment: If ListFragment works for you, there is no reason to migrate. If you are writing a new UI, you might be better off with RecyclerView.

Comment: it works but it handles the click for the entire row, i want to have each item in the row has a different onclick action.

Comment: Then use recycler view.

Comment: i don't know how to use it with fragments that's why i asked this question.